# Prove there exist 135 consecutive integers that each have a perfect cube $>1$ that divides it.

Tags: congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem

As of 22:13, the answer below does not satisfy the constraints of my question, so I'm still **accepting** answers.

---

Prove there exist 135 consecutive integers, $x_1, x_2, ... , x_{135}$, such that for each of these integers, $x_i$, there exists a number $k_i$ such that $k_i>1$ is a perfect cube where $k_i | x_i$.

---

I was told that I could use GCRT to help with this. I got stuck after rewriting the given statement as a system of linear congruences.

Comment: When you say "that divides it", to you mean that each number, $x$, in your list of 135 numbers satisfies $x^3 | x$?

Comment: No, I mean that, for each of the 135 consecutive integers, there exists an integer $x$, such that $x$ is a perfect cube and $x$ divides the $i$th out of the 135.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove there exist 135 consecutive integers that each have a perfect cube >1>1 that divides it.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2516054/prove-there-exist-135-consecutive-integers-that-each-have-a-perfect-cube-11-th)

Comment: If there is a defect in your question, fix your question.  Asking it again wastes many people's effort and makes a future person searching for an answer have to sift through multiple useless variations.

Comment: Okay. I have fixed my question.

Comment: What about your question did change? I cannot see any substantive difference; you restate with more variables what was written before. I ask specifically as there appears to be confusion what your question is.

Comment: Eric Towers interpreted it differently, and then he said that your answer assumed a variation of my question, so I assumed I needed to make my question more explicit.

Comment: That's fine. But does my answer now answer your question or not? You said it does not. Why do you say this? (What Eric Towers said is perfectly compatible with me understanding it right all along.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chose $135$ distinct primes $p_0,\dots,p_{134}$.

Now consider the system
$$X   \equiv -i  \pmod{p_i^3}$$
for $i=0, \dots, 134$.

Since the moduli are pairwise co-prime there exists a solution $x_0$.

It follows that $x_0 + i $ is divisible by $p_i^3$ for each $i$.

Comment: What is $X$ in this example?

Comment: This is not the divisibility criterion OP has written in comments to the Question.

Comment: @quid would you mind editing your answer?

Comment: @EricTowers what *specifically* do you mean? It says for *each* number there is an $x$, that is,  the $x$ can depend on the number. This is reconfirmed by the edit question. Plus, as consecutive integers are co-prime it is manifestly impossible that they are divisible by the same perfect cube.

Comment: @MaxLi the $X$ is the variable in the system. I do not understand what about my answer does not answer your question. Alright I numbered from $0$ to $134$ but that's clearly equivalent. Other than that $x_i = x_0+i$ are the consecutive numbers; each is divisible by $p_i^3$ so  $k_i=p_i^3$.

Comment: @quid : I agree with your assertion about coprimality causing trouble for OP's description in comments.  When pre- and post-edits to the question did not match the "clarification" in the comments, I stopped following this Question.  Maybe the Question has been made unambiguous now.  (I haven't looked.)

Comment: @EricTowers it *did* match, it's just like "for each $\epsilon >0 $ there is a $\delta$" where $\delta$ also depends on the $\epsilon$

Comment: Great answer, thanks.